# Does parasitic capacitance increase the load value of electrodes?

Tags: resistors, capacitance, display, load

I'm reading [Samsung Display's patent about a display notch](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2018/0082630.html). In this patent, the inventors say that providing a parasitic capacitance to scan lines increases their load values. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to show the relevant extract of what they say?

Comment: He asks, why would they even talk about it :)

Comment: This is what they say. "The parasitic capacitance of the parasitic capacitor may increase load values of the second scan lines S2i−1 and S2i and/or the emission control line E2i that are provided in the second pixel area PXA2."